# fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package using `catkin_create_pkg` on my raspberry pi 3 where I have previously installed Ubuntu Xenial and ROS kinetic.
But everytime I am trying to compile the cpp file included in the created package I get the following error

```
fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

looks like it does not see any of the header files included in my cpp file.

I have all set up the same way on my other computer running ubuntu Trusty and ROS indigo. Not sure why this is happening here.

Edit:
This is what I added to my package.xml

```
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>

  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

here is the `Cmakelist.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sphero_move)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
)

## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES sphero_move
CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs geometry_msgs message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(sphero_move
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/sphero_move.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(sphero_move ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(robot_move_node src/robot_move.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(sphero_move_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(robot_move_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 )

add_dependencies(robot_move_node beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS sphero_move sphero_move_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_sphero_move.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

and here is how Im including my header files

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237494/fatal-error:-ros/ros.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [aldolereste](https://answers.ros.org/users/27116/aldolereste/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-20**:
Without seeing at least your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` this is going to be difficult to diagnose. Please include a copy of those files (*without* all the boilerplate comments) in your question. Use the *edit* button/link for that, and the *Preformatted text* button to format them.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-20**:
I don't see a `include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})` anywhere in your snippet (is that the whole file?). Without that, any `#include ..` of ROS related files will fail with the error you mentioned.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2016-06-20**:
right, that idea that gvdhoorn says looks good

**Comment by [aldolereste](https://answers.ros.org/users/27116/aldolereste/) on 2016-06-21**:
Just included it and edited the question above with the full content of my CMakeLists.txt file. No success so far

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-21**:
For future questions: please don't include all the comments whenever you post a `CMakeLists.txt`: they are completely unnecessary, and make it harder to spot problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your `CMakeLists.txt` this appears to be more of a CMake problem than really ROS related, but:

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
> ```

```
project(sphero_move)
```

> ```
> ...
> ```

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
> ```

> ```
> include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
> ```

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
> ```

```
  ...
```

> ```
> )
> ```

This is your problem: you `find_package(..)` the `catkin` package twice. As with other CMake libraries, the second will not necessarily overwrite the first, so it never really does what you want.

Apart from that, you invoke `include_directories(..)` *before* your call to `find_package(catkin ..)` which actually finds the ROS packages you are interested in, and are using. At that point, `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` is empty, leading to no changes to the header search path and ultimately the errors you see.

I'd suggest to merge the two `find_package(catkin ..)` calls, keep the `COMPONENTS` and its arguments, and place the `include_directories(..)` line *after* `find_package(catkin ..)` has had a chance to find your dependencies and populate the variable.

Some references: [catkin/CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) on the ROS wiki, and [catkin 0.6.18 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended)](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) in the Catkin docs (Indigo version). For the second link, see the *C++ catkin library dependencies* and *C++ system library dependencies* sections.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aldolereste](https://answers.ros.org/users/27116/aldolereste/) on 2016-06-23**:
That worked. Thanks

**Comment by [Ahmed Ayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/73458/ahmed-ayman/) on 2021-04-19**:
i have the same issue but my CMakeLists seems fine. i am using ros noetic

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this error with a package that compiled fine in Jade but not Kinetic, it turned out I had spelled `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` wrong.  I think pre-Kinetic includes from every package in a workspace were commingled (so the correctly spelled included in a previously processed package got the includes in).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Ubuntu Xenial and Kinetic Kame, I'm going through the tutorials and right now I'm at "Writing Service&Client" part. When I tried to `catkin_make` the project, I got the same problem, however none of the above mentioned solutions worked for me. Here is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package()
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_client src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_client beginner_tutorials_gencpp)
```

Nothing seems wrong to me (in fact the file is exactly [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/master/create_package_srvclient/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt), without the comments), however I may be missing something.

---

Originally posted by [cydonia](https://answers.ros.org/users/31033/cydonia/) with karma: 11 on 2017-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1